# Adding text before list

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, html-lists

I am trying to make a list like
Element 1.  bird
Element 2.  lion
...

The problem is I don't want to write "Element" for every item. Is there any way to add content to my list?

Comment: Which language are you referring to?

Comment: I am trying to do it with HTML

Comment: i saw that 
li.Madde:before {content:"Element"; text-indent: 10px;}
add text. But i want to make a list 
Element 1
Element 2 

but it does 
1. Element
2. Element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters):

```css
#customlist {
  /* delete default counter */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* create custom counter and set it to 0 */
  counter-reset: elementcounter;
}

#customlist>li:before {
  /* print out "Element " followed by the current counter value */
  content: "Element " counter(elementcounter) ": ";
  /* increment counter */
  counter-increment: elementcounter;
}
```

```html
<ol id="customlist">
  <li>Elephant</li>
  <li>Bird</li>
  <li>Lion</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It did what i want but i have one more problem with that.

I have a nested list like:

Element 1: bird

Element 2: lion
                 Element: white lion
Element 3: dog

when i want to create a nested list it gives increment for every li item and i dont want it to happen do you have any advice?

Comment: I can't really reproduce your bug, but I think the `>` selector should help you. This will only select direct children.

Comment: Right ">" helped me 
Thank you again Zeta :)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays we can use not just counters but also the ::marker pseudo element.

For example, as an answer to this question: [How to replace the dot '.' from an ordered list of type 'a'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67078812/how-to-replace-the-dot-from-an-ordered-list-of-type-a)

```css
ol {
 list-style-type: lower-alpha;
 counter-reset: listcounter;
 padding-left: 30px;
}
li {
 counter-increment: listcounter;
}
li::marker {
 content: counter(listcounter, lower-alpha) ": ";
}
```

```html
<ol type="a">
  <li>Element a</li>
  <li>Element b</li>
  <li>Element c</li>
</ol>
```