# Add custom text to ordered list <li>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use `<ol>` and `<li>` to create an ordered list of cooking directions. However, I need to add the text "Step" before each automatic numeration so it looks as follows:

```
<ol>
    <li>Place bag in freezer, etc...</li>
    <li>Preheat oven</li>
</ol>
```

**Step 1.** Place bag in freezer, etc...

**Step 2.** Preheat oven

---

I tried using the `:before` selector in CSS, but it's placing the custom text "Step" in between the automatic numeration and the content. Here's my CSS:

```
li:before{
    content: "Step ";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And this is the result

**1. Step** Place bag in freezer, etc...

**2. Step** Preheat oven

Is there a way to modify the default behavior so it automatically lists "Step 1", "Step 2", etc?

Comment: Agreed. You can use the exact code from that answer

Comment: Yep. That answer had exactly what I was looking for. I looked all over the place, and couldn't find it before.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to Huangism for pointing me to [Adding text before list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258070/adding-text-before-list), where I found my solution:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: elementcounter;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li:before {
  content: "Step " counter(elementcounter) ". ";
  counter-increment: elementcounter;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Place bag in freezer, etc...</li>
  <li>Preheat oven</li>
</ol>
```

I had to tweak the padding-left because `list-style-type: none;` got rid of the automatic numbering, but still left the space it would've taken up.

**Result:**

**Step 1.** Place bag in freezer, etc...

**Step 2.** Preheat oven

Comment: Its working, thanks. But im trying to change start value. eg. step 5, step 6 .... My code is: "ol[list-type=case]>li:before{
    content: "Step " counter(elementcounter) ":";
    font-weight: bold;
}
ol[list-type=case]>li{
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-increment:elementcounter;
}"