# Custom OL in HTML

Tags: html

I'd like to make an custom OL, these should display letters and no vowels. This means that the first list item would be C for example, then goes D, then skips E and goes to F.

EDIT: someone flagged this as a duplicate. I have searched for the increment, no vowels and starting at C but did not find anything specified as such.

I've tried this

```
<ol type="A">
<li>Here is C </li>
<li>Here is D</li>
<li>Here is F</li>
<li>Here is G</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom text to ordered list <li>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025057/add-custom-text-to-ordered-list-li)

Comment: What happened to B ? Last time I checked, it still wasn't a vowel.

Comment: If you want to start your OL at item 3, than add `start="3"` to your `<ol>` tag, like this `<ol type="A" start="3"></ol>`. See [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol)

Comment: I disagree on this question being a dupe of [Add custom text to ordered list <li>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025057/add-custom-text-to-ordered-list-li). Unless I miss somthing, the provided solution there won't allow the custom increment OP's asking for.

Comment: I've searched before asking the question @SWiggels and have not found the exact question / problem. OL's , sure. But not no vowels / skip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you want to do this depends on which browsers you want to support, and on what *purpose* you're using it for.

## Method 1:

Let's have the bad news first: at the time of writing, Mozilla only.

There's a fairly new @-rule in CSS3, [@counter-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style), which does ***exactly*** what you want.
You can use this if you just want to display any old sequence of symbols for the list counter rather than the regular incrementing values. In this case, if your reasoning is that you don't like vowels or something.

```css
@counter-style novowels {
  system: fixed;
  symbols: B C D F G H J K L M N P Q R S T V W X Z;
  suffix: " ";
}
.consonants > li {
  list-style: novowels;
}
```

```html
<ol class="consonants">
  <li>Here is B</li>
  <li>Here is C</li>
  <li>Here is D</li>
  <li>Here is F</li>
  <li>Here is G</li>
</ol>
```

(Please note that I also reinstated the B, as per the comments to the question.)

## Method 2:

If the list items actually refer to the consonants themselves; that is, the counter items have semantic meanings, it's better to just use the regular `upper-alpha` and put the values of the letters in the list items (where A has the value 1, B is 2 etc).

```css
.consonants {
  list-style: Upper-alpha;
}
```

```html
<ol class="consonants">
  <li value="2">Here is B</li>
  <li value="3">Here is C</li>
  <li value="4">Here is D</li>
  <li value="6">Here is F</li>
  <li value="7">Here is G</li>
</ol>
```

Although the values really are only needed in places where the range is non-sequential (in this case, `value="2"` and `value="6"` are necessary), it's more clear to put all of them in, to show which item means what.

Comment: Thank-you for your marvellous answer! As for the B, in my textbook (university) they specified to start at C. This is why I did not include B in the OP.

Thank you for your help :)