# How to replace the dot '.' from an ordered list of type 'a'

Tags: html, css, sass

I basically need to replace this:

a. Element a
b. Element b
c. Element c

To this:

a: Element a
b: Element b
c: Element c

Tried the following (custom counter as a pseudo-element before each `<li>`):

```
<ol type="a">
  <li>Element a</li>
  <li>Element b</li>
  <li>Element c</li>
</ol>
```

```
ol > li:before {
    content: counter(item) ":";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

But I get this result:
a.1: Element a
b.2: Element b
c.3: Element c

So this seems to work only on regular (numbered) ordered lists. Is there a way to achieve this or would I have to hard code it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove dot '.' from CSS list-style:decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490537/how-to-remove-dot-from-css-list-styledecimal)

Comment: No I already read this that's how I found this method. This works on regular (numbered) lists. But on a list of a different type, I get the above results.

Comment: The question marked as a duplicate does not have a 'modern' answer. Try using the ::marker pseudo element. I'll put your example up there in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025057/add-custom-text-to-ordered-list-li), you can do this :

```
ol {
 list-style-type: none;
 counter-reset: elementcounter;
 padding-left: 0;
}

li:before {
 content: "Step " counter(elementcounter) ". ";
 counter-increment: elementcounter;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

And :

```
<ol>
 <li>Place bag in freezer, etc...</li>
 <li>Preheat oven</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is more precisely what I needed (before my question got closed):           

content: counter(elementcounter, lower-alpha) ": ";